Parsing JSON String from Kafka topics to elastic search
I'm using Strimzi in my k8s cluster and io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector as source connector to use as CDC from postgres to kafka topics, then using io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector to send the data to my elastic search.
The issue that I'm having is with handling jsonb object from my postgres table. In my postgres table, there are some jsonb field that I want to convert into nested object in elastic search.
Here is my kafka topic's message after I did transform it using ExtractNewRecordState transformer
{
  "id": "someId",
  "title": "someTitle",
  "someJsonBField": "[{\"aField\": \"test\"},{\"aField\": \"test\"}]"
}

what I expect is this
{
  "id": "someId",
  "title": "someTitle",
  "someJsonBField": [
    {
      "aField": "test"
    },
    {
      "aField": "test"
    }
  ]
}

I got this error in my sink connector
Indexing failed: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=document_parsing_exception, reason=[1:16] object mapping for [someJsonBField] tried to parse field [someJsonBField] as object, but found a concrete value]]
This error occurred when I try to use pre-mapped index that expect a nested object. This error didn't happen if I use dynamic mapping, however those jsonb field is detected as string in my elastic search index.
I have tried using schema instead of using ExtractNewRecordState but still no luck.
Here is my source connector and sink connector config
spec:
  class: io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
  tasksMax: 2
  config:
    topic.prefix: xxx #
    table.include.list: xxx #
    database.hostname: xxx #
    database.port: 5432
    database.user: xxx
    database.password: xxx
    database.dbname: dbName
    slot.name: replication_slot
    publication.name: publication_name
    decimal.handling.mode: double
    plugin.name: pgoutput
    snapshot.mode: initial
    value.converter: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
    value.converter.schemas.enable: "false"
    
    transforms: unwrap
    transforms.unwrap.type: "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState"
    transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones: "false"

spec:
  class: io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
  tasksMax: 2
  config:
    connector.class: "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector"
    tasks.max: "2"
    topics: xxx
    connection.url: xxx
    connection.username: xxx
    connection.password: xxx
    flush.synchronously: "true"
    value.converter: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
    value.converter.schemas.enable: "false"
    key.ignore: "false"
    schema.ignore: "true"
    errors.tolerance: "all"
    errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name: "failed-records-dlq"
    errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable: "true"
    errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor: "3"
    errors.log.enable: "true"
    errors.log.include.messages: "true"

I have tried many things, with or without jsonConverter. I also tried use schema and schemaless. I've read somewhere that I could solve this by creating custom SMT, but I feel like this issue is not something niche and there should be easier solution than creating my own custom SMT that I do not know.

There's not really anything you can do from Connect other than another transform, specifically a custom one to actually return a nested Struct. You should fix the problem from Elasticsearch side, such as an Ingest Pipeline
